# Unable to see the notification in the dropdown when activity is added to the notification feed

Tags: getstream-io

I am trying to get my head around getstream.io. I am planning to use it for implementing notification functionality.

I am using the react component `StreamApp` on the client side. On the server side I am using Java client.
I am able to add an activity to the notification feed. I get notified on the client side as well about this notification. However, I am not able to see that notification in the dropdown along with other existing notifications.

Front end (client) side code :

```
<StreamApp
      apiKey="apikey"
      appId="appId"                                            token="token here">
         <NotificationDropdown notify />
</StreamApp>
```

Server side (backend) code:

```
       Client client = Client.builder("api key", "secret key").build();
        NotificationFeed feed = client.notificationFeed("notification", "user-one");
        Activity activity = Activity.builder()
                .actor("Mr Beans")
                .verb("like")
                .object("hello world")
                .build();
        feed.addActivity(activity).join();
```

When I run the server side code, I get the notification bubble on the front end. however when I click the bell icon, I cannot see the notification which says "Mr Beans liked hello world". However, I can see the existing ones as shown below.

[image]

Any help on how can I see the activity that I am publishing would be really great. Thanks in advance.

Note:  The api key and token which I am using is from the examples in the documentation.

Regards,
V

Comment: ⚠️please invalidate the API keys that you shared here!

Comment: did you check your browser's console / network tab for errors or warnings?

Comment: oops, didn't realise i was sharing my actual keys. Have now deleted them. Regarding second comment, I am not seeing any errors or warnings

Comment: However, I noticed that after looking at one sample example that following example
Activity activity = Activity.builder()
                .actor("SU:beautifulpanda108")
                .verb("follow")
                .object("SU:user-one")
                .build();
adds the notification and is seen in the dropdown. Why doesn't it show simple notification which I am trying to send.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to create an activity representing a user reaction.

The proper way of doing this is achieved via reaction api:

```java
client.reactions().add(
    "user-one",                             // user ID
    "like",                                 // reaction name
    "ccc38e3e-7def-11e9-9154-127939012af0", // activity user is reacting to
    new FeedID("notification", "user-one")  // feed we want to receive an activity
).join();                                   // representing the reaction
```

If you absolutely need to create the activities yourself - you have two options:

1. Replicate the format of the activity Stream generates:

```java
import static io.getstream.core.utils.Enrichment.createUserReference;
...
Activity like = Activity.builder()
    .actor(createUserReference(user.getID())) // user reference
    .verb("like")
    .object("SA:" + targetActivity.getID())   // activity reference
    .build();

Activity follow = Activity.builder()
    .actor(createUserReference(user.getID()))
    .verb("follow")
    .object(createUserReference(targetUser.getID()))
    .build();
```

2. Reimplement `NotificationDropdown` rendering method to support your custom activity format (see [Notification](https://github.com/GetStream/react-activity-feed/blob/master/src/components/Notification.js) component source code as example):

```js
<StreamApp
    apiKey="<api-key>"
    appId="<app-ID>"
    token="<token>"
>
    <NotificationDropdown notify Group={MyCustomComponent}/>
</StreamApp>
```

Comment: Thanks @Nekuromento, your solution was bang on. I used the second approach to get what I was intending to achieve.